# Umbraco: Document Type Chain by Composition

Tags: c#, content-management-system, umbraco7

Can I use Composition in Umbraco 7.5 to make a property inheritance chain, like BaseType > ContentPage > HomePage, in which ContentPage has its own properties and inherit all properties from BaseType, and HomePage has its own properties and inherit all properties form ContentPage explicitly, and of course from BaseType implicitly?

For some reason, I can make ContentPage to have a composition of type BaseType, but then for HomePage, Umbraco doesn't display ContentPage as an option.

I thought the new Composition feature has replaced document type hierarchies (defining document types under other document types).

Comment: Document type inheritance is still possible and sounds like the solution for your problem.

Comment: I know it still exists, but Umbraco does not remove its deprecated stuff. For example, still I can access doc type fields by dynamic. So, I want to know if it is possible to do so by Composition, or I "have to" use the old doc type inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly fine to still use doctype inheritance. It's not deprecated and in some cases (like yours) preferable over the use of compositions.

They introduced compositions to overcome the downsides of inheritance (for example bloated doctypes with too much properties you don't need) and create reusable sets of properties.

In your case it's fine to use inheritance if you're going to use all properties of ContentPage in the HomePage doctype.
Another possibility is HomePage having the Basetype composition and another composition with the additional ContentPage properties.

Comment: Thanks Mark! I wanted to make sure that I'm not using a obsolete feature.